# web analytics showing no data for extended web application

Tags: web-analytics

A while ago we engaged a consultant, who essentially re-built our SharePoint based website. Initially we had the standard ootb setup, i.e. the single sitecollection was on port 80 and visitors went directly to it. The consultant reconfigured it so that the 'base' web app was on port 100 using the local hostname (with NTLM access for easier searching), and then extended the site on port 80 (with our fully qualified domain and FBA) that the visitors would go to.

Last week I provisioned Web Analytics service application within Central Admin. I also did this at the same time on my dev server (which is the ootb style web app). A week later and Web Analytics reports still show no data, so I'm wondering if because people are visiting the extended site, not the 'base' site, Web Analytics isn't gather said data?

When I check Central Admin > Application Management > Service Applications > Configure service application associations, I only see the 'base' site listed (on port 100). This is why I'm wondering about the extended site not being analyzed.

Any ideas?

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar scenario. Called Microsoft and all we did was make sure that on all of the SharePoint Servers (application, wfe, etc.) the "SharePoint Tracing" Windows service was running as Local System.

After a day we started seeing data on the report. If you need more details reply and I will walk you through these steps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and apologies for the delay in getting back to you (vacation). I checked the "SharePoint 2010 Tracing" service, and it's already Started, automatically, as Local Service, so I think our causes are different. Unless there's more to what you checked than just the service?

Answer (score 0):

So the default web application is running on the :100 host header.  Is the web application currently connected to the Web Analytics under service connections?

Comment: The web application on port 100 is associated yes, as I mentioned in my original question. The extended site (on port 443) is not listed, and there seems to be no way to add it.

Comment: You don't need to add the extended site.  You just need to point to the internal site which is hosted on :100.  It is a best practices to configure service applications to use internal zones that use Windows Authentication to successfully connect to the application.  There are many instances, such as my environment, where services cannot connection to the application over 442 due to multi-factor authentication methods that are enforced.

Comment: OK, then there must be another cause of this. When I look at the Service Application Associations list I see `http://myserver:100` listed under `Web Application / Service Application`, and that the `Application Proxy Group` is `default` and under the list of `Application Proxies` I see `Web Analytics Service Application 1`. I also know that the `Web Analytics Service Application and it's Proxy are both started. What else could this be? Do I have to publish the service application? Thanks for the help so far - much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the SA with 1 farm you do not need to publish it.  If you plan to us it for multiple farms you need to publish it.  Verify your config by following this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382.aspx#section2

Comment: As far as I can tell, I setup Web Analytics correctly, according to the link you provided (which I'd used before). I'm wondering if there is a way to look (and only look) at the databases to see if any content is being gathered? Setting up Web Analytics, I specified WAStaging and WAReporting as my database names. I didn't see any specific guidance on that, so I figured I could just make them up? (those are what I called them on the working DEV server).

Comment: In case it helps track down my issue, I found 6 (currently) .usage files in my 14/LOGS folder. I read somewhere that these are text files and I should see URLs in them, but for the most part they are binary looking files, containing thousands of ÿ characters and the occasional line saying `XMicrosoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c8Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobUsageEntrym_ServiceIdm_WebApplicationIdm_JobId m_ServerIdm_Statusm_StartTime m_EndTimem_WebApplicationName m_JobTitle m_Request...` and more.

Comment: You can name the databases anything.  There are different ways to organize naming conventions when dealing with the amount of database like adding a common prefix among farm databases but its completely optional- so db name should not be an issue.  One final thing you can check on the Web Analytics Service Application is that the local farm has full control.  Under SA, highlight web analytics > in Ribbon select permissions to confirm Local Farm has full control.  Also, backing up a bit, ensure that your web analytics service and web analytics data processing services are running in your farm.

Comment: I am assuming they are at this point.

Right, that occasional line you posted would suggest everything is reporting correctly in the .usage file.  If you scroll down more, you will see more URL strings.  some containing your internal site: http://machineName:32843 or http://machineIP:32843. 

At this point, I would say try to run a report and post your findings.  Run a report from your web application under site settings.  It would be a good idea to run the web analytics timer jobs as well.

Comment: Also, keep an eye on the application log to see if it is reporting any web analytics errors.  You could also keep an eye on the size of your web analytics dbs over a period of time and see if they are growing.

I probably should have asked this earlier but how many servers are in this farm?  I am assuming you are not using Kerberous is that correct?

Let me know if this helps at all.